# How do i stop jtattoo from making my second jframe go full screen?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Recently started using jframe.
My application consist of 2 jframes login and menu.
when login is successful menu jframe is instantiated.
with jtattoo am using texture Laf so i can customize everything
the menu screen currently always opens in full screen as in it even hides the windows taskbar.
i want it to be be maximized but not full screen.

the jtattoo code in the constructor of login frame :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("textureSet", "Custom");
        props.put("backgroundTexture", ImageHelper.loadImage("../images/f.jpg"));
        props.put("alterBackgroundTexture",ImageHelper.loadImage("../images/RolloverTexture.gif"));
        props.put("rolloverTexture", ImageHelper.loadImage("../images/k.gif"));
        props.put("selectedTexture", ImageHelper.loadImage("../images/DarkBackgroundTexture.jpg"));
        props.setProperty("buttonColorLight", "240 240 240");
        props.setProperty("buttonColorDark", "220 220 220");=
        props.setProperty("centerWindowTitle", "on");
        TextureLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(props);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); before the components of menu frame are visible